# How do I get colors and a correct character set with screen through PuTTY?

Tags: command-line, putty, gnu-screen

Screen session over putty connections from windows are colorless and have a character set problem (shows in curses applications like aptitude). A screen session on a proper terminal works just fine.

How do I configure putty to make this work properly?

It's an ubuntu server.

Comment: what's the output of the following command in your terminal session?   echo $TERM

Comment: Not really an answer, colors work here, and with screen. This link, however, has a number of tips - http://dag.wieers.com/blog/content/improving-putty-settings-on-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the colors, but for the characters, you need to set putty to use UTF-8 as the code page.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for both the characters and the colors.

Comment: @John, an upvote and/or accepting as the correct answer is the proper way to say thanks ;)

Comment: I did accept it some time ago (apparently after you wrote this), but it appears I lack the required reputation to vote you up, sorry.